# Laplacian eigenvalues of trees

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a graph and $L$ is its Laplacian matrix and $0=\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq \cdots \leq \mu_n$ are are its Laplacian eigenvalues. We know that the multiplicity of $\mu_2$ in star $K_{1,n-1}$ is $n-2$. I wanted to know that is there any other trees that their multiplicity of $\mu_2$ be greater than $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many of such types.
Here is one such example:
[image: Ex]

$$L=\begin{bmatrix}    
3 &    -1  &   0  &  -1  &  -1  &   0  &   0\\
-1 &    2  &  -1  &   0  &   0  &   0  &   0\\
0  &  -1   &  1   &  0   &  0   &  0  &   0\\
    -1 &    0  &   0  &   2   &  0  &   0 &   -1\\
    -1  &   0   &  0  &   0  &   2  &  -1   &  0\\
   0 &    0 &    0 &    0  &  -1 &    1  &   0\\
     0 &    0  &   0 &   -1  &   0 &    0 &    1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\text{eig}(L)=\begin{pmatrix}  0 &   \mathbf{0.3820} &   \mathbf{0.3820} &   1.5858 &   2.6180 &   2.6180  &  4.4142\end{pmatrix}.$$